# Who Execute Transaction in PoA

Tags: private-blockchain, proof-of-authority

In PoW, every full-nodes executes contracts of a block to confirm that the miner was doing honest work.

What about in PoA (proof-of-Authority)?

a. Only authorities will execute the contracts to confirm the block

b. Any full-nodes (with or without authority access) will execute the contracts to confirm the block

Thank you in advance!